# Realtime transparent painting

Tags: texture-painting

I want to create transparent texture using texture paint. Everything works fine but i'm just not convenient of how to preview the trasparent area. How to paint the transparent area and see the result instantly ? I'm using Blender 2.8. Eevee can't show transparent texture (i don't know if this is a bug) so i use cycle to preview. The problem is when i paint in cycle mode , it records my strokes, but doesn't update that transparent area i paint. I only can paint  black on white texture in realtime (when turn on overlay texture paint).

I just want to paint that transparent texture and see the result immediately.

Any idea ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is BG? Background? Is EEVEE answer acceptable?

Comment: Need screen shots of what you have now, as well as notes on set up and which Renderer and which version of Blender, etc.

Comment: Hi, sorry if i'm not clear enough. I 've just uploaded some images and edit my questions. Basically i just want to paint the transparent area and see the result (hole) immediately.

Comment: Using a comment because I am unsure of your issues here - but here is a file that works for me using Eevee and a generated image set up with nodes, material set to Alpha Blend in properties instead of Opaque. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGAunKcz3OMFzGp5XfOWqRGvq0sSJWxX/view?usp=sharing